# How to make a one way table with two columns in R?

Tags: r

Suppose I have a column of data frame with A,A,A,B,B,A,C,C, and I want to make a table consists of two columns, the first column I want to name it "letters", the second column I name it "counts". How can I do it? I tried use table(), but I get something different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try

```
setNames(as.data.frame(table(v1)), c('letters', 'counts'))
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c('A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'C')
```